# Determining even/odd using a array_filter

Tags: php, arrays

I am digging deeper into the array_filter() of php. I've understand the basic idea of it but fall into new problem.

```
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5];

$result = array_filter($array, function ($var){
              return $var & 1;
          });
```

If I dump the **$result**  it looks like:

```
array:3 [
  "a" => 1
  "c" => 3
  "e" => 5
]
```

I want to know how  **return $var & 1;** works behind the scene in the callback function of array_filter() .

Comment: Not sure what the actual question is here. Sounds like you are simply not aware what the `&` operator does? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Exactly. I was not aware of bitwise operator. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) keeps the values that produce truthy result for the callback and removes the values that don't.

This expression actually checks if the number is odd:

```php
$number & 1
```

Why? because it performs bitwise AND operation with `1`. So, odd numbers have `1` as their last digit in binary representation and even numbers have `0`.

When you perform bitwise AND, every corresponding digit computes to `1` when both digits are `1` and `0` otherwise. So:

```
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
3 = 0011
4 = 0100
5 = 0101
// etc.
```

Now, you can apply AND operation:

```
    0001 = 1
AND 0001
  = 0001 = 1 (odd)

    0010 = 2
AND 0001
  = 0000 = 0 (even)

    1001 = 9
AND 0001
  = 0001 = 1 (odd)
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hm... That answers the title but not the acutal question.

Comment: I thought that `% 1` was OP's trial to determine the odd.

Comment: You answer "Piece of cake. You need a modulo operator:". The question was "
I want to know how return $var & 1; works behind the scene in the callback function of array_filter() ." :)

Comment: No problem. I just was nitpicking

Comment: Awesome. Couldn't be better.